# How can I retrieve the corresponding DOI for an academic article's (source) URL?

Tags: url, doi

I have assembled a large collection of URLs pertaining to scientific papers from social media (e.g. "https://www.jni-journal.com/article/S0165-5728(21)00282-4/fulltext)". I would now like to perform bibliometric/scientometric analyses of these articles by looking them up in Web of Science, Scopus or similar. However, most of these scientometric databases use the article's DOI as the entry point for querying. My question is therefore: how can I "convert" a URL into its corresponding DOI programmatically, and without having to scrape the DOI from the publisher's website? Essentially, I am looking for the type of link resolution that Crossref offers, but in the opposite direction (from URL to DOI rather than the other way around). Any suggestions on how to approach this would be most welcome.